# C++ XE2 - How to read Nested JSON?

Tags: json, nested-sets, c++builder-xe2

I have been searching quite a while now for how to read a nested JSON with C++ Builder XE2 `TJSONObject`.

There are a few examples in Delphi but they use the `TJSONValue` object, but in the C++ version this class has a pure virtual function and can not be created.

Some example JSON:

```
{
  "totalHits": 4170,
  "totalCount": 4170,
  "startIndex": 0,
  "adverts": [
    {
      "Id": "14380005",
      "companyInfo": {
        "companyName": "Clarion Hotel Sign",
        "orgNumber": "5564660107",
        "companyText": "hotell"
      },
      "address": {
        "streetName": "Street race 2",
        "postCode": "101 26",
        "postArea": "MY AREA",
        "postBox": "Box 310"
      },
      "homepage": "www.mypage.net"
    }
  ]
}
```

The whole JSON is stored in the JSON object, trust me, it's in there :)

```
TJSONObject *JSON = new TJSONObject;
```

I have no problem to get the value for totalHits and totalCount, but how do I get the `"companyName"` value?!?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post this belated answer for someone else who meets the same problems in the future....

```
TJSONArray* jArray = (TJSONArray* )JSON->Get("adverts")->JsonValue;
TJSONObject* jCompanyInfo = (TJSONObject*)((TJSONObject*)jArray->Get(0))
       ->Get("companyInfo")->JsonValue);
String companyName =  jCompanyInfo->Get("companyName")->JsonValue->Value());
```

Comment: I created a "Document" with Key=value StringList hierarchy. It was easier to search and read in this way. I'm accepting your answer since I guess that is the proper way to do it :)